# MYSQL multiple inner join cause "Column clause is ambiguous"

Tags: mysql

i try to join 3 tables, but it seems not to work. I can join the two first tables without any problem but when i join the third one, then i get `Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous`

```
SELECT Json_arrayagg(Json_object('id', p.id, 'text', p.text, 'created_at',
                            p.created_at, 'likes',
                                          p.likes, 'user',
                            Json_object('name', u.NAME, 'photo_url',
                            u.photo_url), 'comments',
                                          Json_object('text', c.text,
                                          'created_at',
                                          c.created_at))) AS posts
FROM   posts p
       INNER JOIN users u
               ON u.id = p.user_id
       INNER JOIN post_comments c
               ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE ` user_id ` = :userId
ORDER  BY p.id DESC
```

Comment: A MySQL server will never throw a 500 **HTTP** error! Get the error **MySQL** is throwing and edit it into the question.

Comment: Ah well it's the php which execute the mysql code

Comment: Which is missing in the post and probably irrelevant anyway, if the query really is the cause of the issue. (And technically it's not even PHP that throws the HTTP 500 but the web server. The PHP program might cause it to do so though.)

Comment: Well the query is the issue, as soon i remove the third inner join. Everything functions normal. Sorry i'm new to this, i have no idea how to debug mysql code

Comment: Forget PHP for a moment (I guess you already did as you didn't tag it) and use an SQL client to directly access the database and get the error. Then [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Say which value `:userId` has for your example. Post the error message the query causes.

Comment: Cheers man, i tried out what you said. I got this: `Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous`

Comment: @Printer `ambiguous` means that it needs to know the table where to take it from. So it should be `table_name.user_id`

Comment: Qualify it. `p.user_id = :userId` or even better `u.id = :userId`.

Comment: Thanks guys that sorted my issue, also learned how to debug mysql query ^^